# no registra datos sqlite

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Este es el método para registrar los datos, ya validé que `registro` contenga los datos a enviar, sin embargo no registra los mismo, he probado de diferentes maneras sin embargo me sigue sin registrar los datos, ya revisé cuidadosamente cada nombre de variables y metodos para descartar error mío, pero no encontre eso fuera el error.

```
public void RegistrarUsers(View view){

    conexionSQLiteHelper conexion = new conexionSQLiteHelper(this, "db_usuario", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase baseDatos = conexion.getWritableDatabase();

    String name = usuario.getText().toString();
    String mail = correo.getText().toString();
    String pass = clave.getText().toString();

    if ( !name.isEmpty() && !mail.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty() ){
        if ( pass.length() >= 4 ){

            ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

            registro.put(utilidadesGuardar.usuario, name);
            registro.put(utilidadesGuardar.correo, mail);
            registro.put(utilidadesGuardar.contraseña, pass);

            Long idResultado = baseDatos.insert(utilidadesGuardar.create_table_usuario, null, registro);

            if( idResultado == -1) Toast.makeText(this, "Error with inserting users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else Toast.makeText(this, "users created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            baseDatos.close();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Registrarse.this, "La clave debe tener 4 caracteres", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Registrarse.this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    usuario.setText("");
    correo.setText("");
    clave.setText("");
}
```

Esta es la clase `utilidadesGuardar` que se hace referencia en `basedatos.insert` :

```
public class utilidadesGuardar {

    //tabla usuarios
    public static final String tabla_usuario="usuario";
    public static final String usuario="usuario";
    public static final String correo="correo";
    public static final String contraseña="contraseña";

    public static final String create_table_usuario = "CREATE TABLE " + tabla_usuario
            +" ("+ usuario + "TEXT, "
            + correo + "TEXT, "
            + contraseña +"TEXT)";
     }
}
```

Esta es la conexión

```
public class conexionSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public conexionSQLiteHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override// genera las tablas
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(utilidadesGuardar.create_table_usuario);
    }

    @Override// verifica que no exista una version de la db
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuario");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Y esta es la base de datos ( ya tiene el set y get pero no lo añadí para no hacer mas extenso el código)

```
public class baseDatos {

    private String usuario;
    private String correo;
    private String contraseña;

    public baseDatos(String usuario, String correo, String contraseña) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.contraseña = contraseña;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Soy principiante, pero por lo que veo, en `RegistrarUser()` no veo de donde coges los datos de usuario, **email** y **clave**... Teniendo en cuenta que pareces haberte liado un poco ya que utilizas en `baseDatos()` y `utilidadesGuardar()` `contraseña` en vez de `clave`.

En cuanto al SQLite, te puedo poner uno de mis simples códigos que utilizo yo y no me da ningún error, teniendo en cuenta que utilizo un `ArrayList<String>` para recoger los create y los inserts. Ya que por lo que veo, en `onUpgrade()` lo que yo hago es eliminar tablas y las vuelvo a generar con los datos nuevos.

```java
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "PruebaSQL";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MySQLiteHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // **************************************
        // * Metode abreviat del execucio SQL   *
        // **************************************

        for (String dbSQL : dataBaseSQL) {
            db.execSQL(dbSQL);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // **************************************
        // * Metode abreviat del execucio SQL   *
        // **************************************

        for (String dbSQL : dataBaseSQL) {
            db.execSQL(dbSQL);
        }
    }
}
```

Y los datos del Array...dataBaeSQL... ==> ArrayList
cada linea pertenece a un String, y para poder utilizar el mismo array, primero me aseguro de que no existan las tablas y añadiendo los nuevos inserts para que funcione el `onUpgrade()`.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tiendas;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS poblaciones;
CREATE TABLE poblaciones (codi TEXT PRIMARY KEY, nom TEXT NOT NULL, cp TEXT, lat REAL, lon REAL);

INSERT INTO tiendas (codi, nom, lat, lon, poblacion, telefono, direc, foto, tipo) VALUES ('t2','Nombre', '39.22', '-0.40', 'm1', '961234567', 'C/ Comandante, 26' ,'url foto','Farmacia');
```

Comment: Gracias, sabia que tenia todo bien, desinstale la aplicacion y la reinstale, con ello se soluciono el problema, a mi pareces el problema estaba en el cache de la app porque habia validado bien los datos, probare tu version de manejar los datos a vre como me va, gracias